# Can't run C on Geany

Tags: compiling, c, execute-command, geany

I'm having trouble in running C code from Geany. The code compiles successfully, but when I try to execute it, it shows on Terminal:

```
/tmp/geany_run_script_I007A0.sh: 7: /tmp/geany_run_script_I007A0.sh: ./test: not found
```

I saved the program as `test.c`.